# Is it possible to share textures between processes without texture's data copy?

Tags: opengl, textures, ipc, vulkan

I tought that it might work using the Vulkan's external memory extension by allocating the memory in process A, create a HANDLE to that memory and pass that HANDLE via shared memory to process B.

But this seems is not possible as HANDLE is actually just a void* and for different processes exist different memory mapping, so the pointer/HANDLE is actually **not transferable between processes**.

Is there some way how to get the handle somehow and recreate the GL texture/ VK image in different process without copying all images's pixel data (like when PBO is used)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow: I guess you reimport the HANDLE in the second process with `ImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT` ? Handle is a technically a void*, but why would that be a problem and what does it have to do with memory mapping? As far as I understand the external memory handling, HANDLE is a pointer to external memory, not to memory in your programs address space. And you don't access that pointer with anything else than `ImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT` anyway, so as long as that method handles it correctly, it should be fine.

Comment: The [extension spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_external_objects_win32.txt) also states this: "<handle> is a windows HANDLE cast to the type "void*"". It's not a pointer, it's a handle cast into a pointer.

Comment: As `winnt.h` states `typedef void *HANDLE;`, so yes HANDLE is just typedef for void* I should tag the questuion C++/C. Although I obtain HANDLE in process A, via `vkGetMemoryWin32HandleKHR` and then I store that HANDLE in a shared memory and try to reuse it in process B, but it is not working. In process B it is invalid, as the pointer value (imported HANDLE) there points to different memory space, or at last it seems so. If you know about any example using Vulkan + memory HANDLES in IPC way, pls let me know, as I did not found anything.

Comment: To be clear I am inporting the HANDLE in process B using `glImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT`. Maybe I should avoid that GL call and use something for Vulkan instead (but for interop within one process export in VK and import in GL works OK)?

Comment: Using `glImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT` is exactly what you are supposed to call. I think there is still a conceptual misunderstanding: Even though HANDLE is a void* it is not a "normal" memory pointer. It's a pointer to external memory, not to your applications memory. You can't access it with a debugger; how do you currently identify that the pointer is invalid? Any exception? Error message? I used this extension ages ago and couldn't find the blog anymore, but this one (though not in C++) uses basically the same steps: https://bxt.rs/blog/fast-half-life-video-recording-with-vulkan/

Comment: @BDL Then it would make sense (that the handle is actaully different memory not app's memory map based one), but that mean that I should be completely OK to obtain a handle via `vkGetMemoryWin32HandleKHR` and put the value to the shared memory, open that shared mem. in process B read the value and use it with `glImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT`, or not?

Comment: The way you describe it is exactly how it should work. If it doesn't work, then you should probably ask a new question and show your code

Comment: The hlaf-life link is just showing the multithread approach, not multiprocess, as what I am able to understand with mine limited Rust knowledge. This is not the case, as such approach I already have working. `DuplicateHandle` seems the way to go for me, though I am still getting some errors, but at last I got some progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To transfer a `HANDLE` to a different process use the function [`DuplicateHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle), which will create a duplicate handle referencing the same object, but in the other process. Then you'll have to pass the value of that new `HANDLE` (which isn't usable in the original process) to the other process by some means of IPC. You could use shared memory, or send a message, or… well whatever that allows you to send the other process an integer of `sizeof(void*)`, i.e. in terms of C a `uintptr_t`. You then just cast the `HANDLE` to a `uintptr_t` send that numeric value to the other process, where you cast it back to a `HANDLE`.

You have to do this manually, since there's no mechanism in place, that tells a process that suddenly and out of the blue an entirely new `HANDLE` was magicked into their task context.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing, except calling `DuplicateHandle`, I hope this was the problem, thank you very much. I will try it out and accept the answer, if it solves the issue.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me in the end. Just note for anybody reading this, you can `DuplicateHandle` just once in the client (which is what you need to do, if you do not know the PID (or names) of potential clients within server process).